# Python Dictionary transpose rows as column

Tags: python, dictionary, transpose

I have a CSV file that will be imported and converted into a dictionary.

```
with open(r"DictionaryQuestion.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in map(dict, csvReader):
    print(row)
```

[Example Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sttr9.png)

I want to be able to transpose the data so that the Discount & NonDiscount rows will be added as columns with their associated amount as well as getting rid of duplicates. Essentially, I want a new dictionary so that I can zip through it.

This is the desired output.

[Desired Output as Dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Lexl.png)

Comment: Can you copy and paste the data as code/text rather than an image?

Comment: Try pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html  You can do it manually, but it probably won't be as fast and it definitely won't be as easy.

Comment: Can you share sample data of your input? Otherwise, we can't reproduce your problem. If you don't want to, I suggest you take a look at a library named [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). You'd want to specifically search for `.read_csv()` and `.pivot_table()`

Comment: @ArturoSbr thank you for the feedback. I will be sure to do that for the next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group records by productId and then update your data.

Below I've converted a list which has records same as yours and created new list with data as expected.

```py
data = [
    {
        "ProductId": "1", "Brand": "Brand1", "rateamount": 1, "rate_type": "Discount" 
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "1", "Brand": "Brand1", "rateamount": 2, "rate_type": "NonDiscount" 
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "2", "Brand": "Brand2", "rateamount": 3, "rate_type": "Discount" 
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "2", "Brand": "Brand2", "rateamount": 4, "rate_type": "NonDiscount" 
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "3", "Brand": "Brand3", "rateamount": 5, "rate_type": "Discount" 
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "3", "Brand": "Brand3", "rateamount": 6, "rate_type": "NonDiscount" 
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "4", "Brand": "Brand4", "rateamount": 7, "rate_type": "Discount" 
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "4", "Brand": "Brand4", "rateamount": 2, "rate_type": "NonDiscount" 
    },
]
```

## Solution

Assuming you data is ordered by `productId`, otherwise you'll need to order it before grouping.

```py
import itertools

groups = itertools.groupby(data, lambda e: {"ProductId": e["ProductId"], "Brand": e["Brand"]})

output = []
for group, items in groups:
    el = dict(group)
    for item in items:
        if item["rate_type"] == "Discount":
            el["Discount"] = item["rateamount"]
        else:
            el["NonDiscount"] = item["rateamount"]
    output.append(el)

print(output)
```

Above for loop can be converted to a map

```py
import itertools

groups = itertools.groupby(data, lambda e: {"ProductId": e["ProductId"], "Brand": e["Brand"]})

output = map(
    lambda group: dict(
    **group[0],
    **{
        item["rate_type"]: item["rateamount"] for item in group[1]
    }),
    groups
)

print(list(output))
```

Both prints

```json
[
 {'ProductId': '1', 'Brand': 'Brand1', 'Discount': 1, 'NonDiscount': 2},
 {'ProductId': '2', 'Brand': 'Brand2', 'Discount': 3, 'NonDiscount': 4},
 {'ProductId': '3', 'Brand': 'Brand3', 'Discount': 5, 'NonDiscount': 6},
 {'ProductId': '4', 'Brand': 'Brand4', 'Discount': 7, 'NonDiscount': 2}
]
```

Comment: The first solution was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!